# Не понимаю в чём дело, ошибка ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{props.tasks.map((t) => {
          const onChangeTitle = (value: string) => {
            props.onChangeTitle(t.id, value, props.id);
          };

          return (
            <li key={t.id} className={t.isDone === true ? "is-done" : ""}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  props.changeCheckbox(t.id, e.currentTarget.checked, props.id)
                }
                checked={t.isDone}
              />
              <EditableSpan title={t.title} onChange={onChangeTitle} />
              <button onClick={() => props.removeItem(t.id, props.id)}>
                x
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
```

в onChange в EditableSpan вылазит ошибка: Type '{ title: string; onChange: (value: string) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & EditableSpanPropsType'.
Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & EditableSpanPropsType'.

А вот и сам EditableSpan:

```
type EditableSpanPropsType = {
  title: string;
  onChangeTitle: (value: string) => void;
};

function EditableSpan(props: EditableSpanPropsType) {
  const [editmode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);

  const activateEditMode = () => {
    setEditMode(true);
    setTitle(props.title);
  };
  const activateViewMode = () => {
    setEditMode(false);
    props.onChangeTitle(title);
  };
  const onChangeHandler = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setTitle(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return editmode ? (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={title}
      onChange={onChangeHandler}
      onBlur={activateViewMode}
      autoFocus
    />
  ) : (
    <span onDoubleClick={activateEditMode}>{props.title}</span>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В компонент `EditableSpan` вы передаете атрибут `onChange` вместо `onChangeTitle`.

Тут есть два решения.

---

Тип `EditableSpanPropsType` нужно поменять.

```
type EditableSpanPropsType = {
  title: string;
  onChangeTitle: (value: string) => void;
};
```

Вот так.

```
type EditableSpanPropsType = {
  title: string;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
};
```

---

Второе решение.

Вместо `onChange` передаете `onChangeTitle`.

```
<EditableSpan title={t.title} onChangeTitle={onChangeTitle} />
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо